# java relative path

Tags: java, relative-path

Using the snippet below throws me a null pointer exception, but i can't find the reason:

```
String path = ResourcesLoader.class.getResource("src/i3d/resourcesloader/libraries/lib.txt").toString();
```

[image]

Am i using the `getResources` wrong? I even tried to enter the full path, like "D:\Workspace...", double backslashes, double forwardslashes but i get the exception of null pointer. The only thing i haven't tried is using java's path separator, but that shouldn't be a problem at this moment as it runs on Windows. What do i miss?

Thanks!

Comment: What about i3d/resourcesloader/libraries/lib.txt

Comment: What happens if you remove the src part from your path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getResource` [searches via the classloader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29), so typically and simplified in the classpath. The `src` folder is not in the classpath – it only exists for the build. Depending on your build system (ANT, Maven, IDE internal) a resources folder may be merged into the classpath. You put your resource directly into the source folder which will also work (if the build process copies all non-Java resources to the class output folder or if the source folder is used for the output of the generated classes).

`/` is the root for your resources if you use absolute resource locations. It is equivalent to the root *within* the `src` folder. `/i3d/resourcesloader/libraries/lib.txt` would be the correct way to access the resource.

It would be nicer to separate the resources in a separate folder that is merged by the build tool (e.g. in Maven: `/src/main/java`, `/src/main/resources`).

Comment: `/i3d/resourcesloader/libraries/lib.txt` works just fine,thx.

Comment: ...it looks like if i use `/i3d/resourcesloader/libraries/lib.txt` i can't pass the string to a file constructor because it acts like it creates an empty file, not linking with the existing one at that adress. Instead, if i use `src/i3d/resourcesloader/libraries/lib.txt` in the File constructor it reads the existing one. I'm confused!

Comment: `getResource` returns an `URL`. Use this, don't `toString` it. Better yet: In most cases you can just use `getResourceAsStream` and don't need any manual work with file handles.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using NetBeans?

Just create a folder called `src\resources`, get your files inside there, and call `this.getClass().getResource("lib.txt");`.

Netbeans will pack that properly when building and the resources will be in the main folder inside the jar, so you can get without having to specify their folder.

Comment: i've tried your way but it does't seem to find the file;still null pointer. using the `/i3d/resourcesloader/libraries/lib.txt` works though.

Answer (score 1):

You should only provide relative path from your classloading point (ie without `src`):

```
String path = ResourcesLoader.class.getResource("/i3d/resourcesloader/libraries/lib.txt").toString();
```