# How to embed a python script in a JAR/JAVA package?

Tags: java, python, jar, execute

I just call a script inside the Java code:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("PlotFiles.py" + FinalCallStringCMD + " -w 1");
 } catch (IOException ex) {// catch ex   }
```

I have then two question: 
**1)** How can I indicate the script in the code as part of the package and not as hardcoded path (ex. `/users/pinc/Plot.py`)
**2)** How can I embed the Python script in the JAR file, so I can always call it?

Comment: As far as I concern, the JAR file is an archive where you zip resources. I wanted to know if there is a method to embed also a python script as resource. What did you understand?

Comment: Jython might do what you want, but I'm not certain of that.

Comment: I am aware of Jython, but is it not too powerful for only a execution call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think you could do something similar to the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466631/java-relative-path), which should solve both issues.  I.E., put the Python file in some location below the `src` directory, and then load it using a relative path with the `src` directory as the "root", using the `ResourcesLoader`.

I think you could call the getPath() method on the returned URL to achieve your needs, but I haven't tried this.

Answer (score 0):

Load the scripts as resources from your jar file and use jython via a javax.script.ScriptEngineManager to execute them.